# Why won't my images print to the PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have bitmaps in "C://" which name is "1.bmp", "2.bmp", "3.bmp" etc and I'm trying to print these images but the print document is empty (the images are in correct path)

Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    for (int indice = 0; indice < nPaginasPDF + 1; indice++)
    {
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Print_Page);
    }
    PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();

    dlg.Document = pd;
    dlg.ShowDialog();
    pd.Print();
}       

private void Print_Page(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    nPaginasImpressas++;
    System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\" + nPaginasImpressas + ".bmp");
    Point p = new Point(891, 1350);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
}
```

Comment: nPaginasImpressas.ToString() when concantenated right?

Comment: I'm trying change the path      var path = "C:\" + nPaginasImpressas.ToString() + ".bmp"; 
but I'm getting compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the process by which pages are printed leverages the `PrintPageEventArgs` class and not attaching the event multiple times. Consider the following code:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Print_Page);
    PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();

    dlg.Document = pd;
    dlg.ShowDialog();
    pd.Print();
}       

private void Print_Page(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    nPaginasImpressas++;
    System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\" + nPaginasImpressas + ".bmp");
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);

    e.HasMorePages = File.Exists("C:\\" + (nPaginasImpressas + 1) + ".bmp");
}
```

this code should allow you to print multiple pages. But note the change to the `Point` -which was quite suspect to me, and then the leverage of `HasMorePages`.

Comment: @AranhaSilva, it will continue to print as long as it finds a bitmap at the next ordinal, take note to this line `e.HasMorePages = File.Exists("C:\\" + (nPaginasImpressas + 1) + ".bmp");`.

Comment: It works great...and my code too...the problem was  Point p = new Point(891, 1350);

Comment: @AranhaSilva, I'm glad I could be of assistance!